# Inversion and alternative bass note

Tags: piano, chords, chord-inversions

On the Am/G:  Is this an Am with 2nd inversion and an alternative bass note G?

On the C/G:  Is this a C with an alternative bass note G?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am/G is an Am chord over the bass note G.   It differs from a last-inversion Am7 chord in that the 7th, G, is specifically NOT included anywhere except as the lowest note.

There's no such complication with C/G.   G is part of a C major triad, so C/G is simply a second inversion C major chord.

Answer (score 2):

Inversions are always named from which note is *lowest*. Since in the Am bar, the lowest note is G (signified by the slash G), it actually makes an Am7 chord, and, since the G is lowest, that inversion is called 3rd.

With C/G, the lowest note is G, under a C major chord. That gives it the name 2nd inversion.

It matters not in which order the higher notes are played or written, it's a always the lowest note which defines the inversion. Root lowest = *Root*, 3rd lowest = 1st inversion, 5th lowest = 2nd inversion, 7th lowest = 3rd inversion. Occasionally, the lowest note is not from a simple chord, so it's easier to use a slash. As in C/D. not really an inversion then, though.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the arpeggiation in the bass wouldn't be taken into account where, as here, it's faster than the harmonic rhythm.  In other words, an analyst should not trouble herself to specify eight successive inversions for each measure.

Answer (score 1):

C/G = CEG over G = G,C,E ...yes! (0 2nd inversion -> 5th = basstone

Am/G= ACE above G = G,A,C,E. This is the 3rd inversion of Am7

Am7 root-position = A,C,E,G

1st inversion = C,E,G,A (basstone = 3rd)

2nd inversion = E,G,A,C (basstone = 5th)

3rd inversion = G,A,C,E (basstone = 7th)